# How to return all the rows from t1 using LEFT JOIN of t3 in SQL

Tags: mysql, select

```
t1 (addition)
-----
id
t2_fk (modelpaper)
questions (100 questions)

t2 (modelpaper)
-----
id

t3 (student answers)
-----
id
t1_fk 
t2_fk
ans (out of 100 they completed only 75)
```

I want to join t3 and still show all 100 questions. But when i do (see 3rd one) it showed me different number. how can i do that.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t1 
WHERE t2_FK = 60
// 100

SELECT COUNT(t1.id) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_fk 
WHERE t1.t2_FK = 60
// 100

SELECT COUNT(t1.id) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_fk LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_fk 
WHERE t1.t2_FK = 60
// 4600
```

Comment: Each record in `t1` have only one matched record in `t2`. But each record in `t2` have multiple matched records in `t3` - it is the cause why the number of output records is too high. Nevertheless each record from `t1` is listed in output at least once.

Comment: i do can see that, but is there any way to show `t1` and `t2` separately.

Comment: Create a fiddle and show desired result for it. Or at least replace verbal tables structures descriptions with CREATE TABLE, give some example INSERT INTO and show the result for this sample data.